# How do I remove bundles from a p2 mirror?

Tags: eclipse, mirror, p2

I've created a p2 mirror as described in various places:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Ant_Tasks
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Ant_Tasks/Partial_Mirroring/Example
- http://ramblingabout.wordpress.com/2009/06/23/naive-scripts-for-mirroring-p2-repositories/

I've filled it with the bundles for Eclipse 3.7. It now contains stuff like ECF and the C++ tools which I won't need.

What is the best way to clean those from a repo? Can I remove them at all or do I have to run the mirror script again using a partial mirror?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `p2.remove.iu` Ant task. Look for this and other useful p2 repository tasks [here](http://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_repositorytasks.htm).